# No puedo ver los proyectos en JBOSS

Tags: java, jboss

Estoy realizando unas mejoras en un proyecto Java, que utiliza JBOSS. El problema que tengo es que no consigo siquiera ver los proyectos, ya que al lanzar el workbench:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque se han arrancado los servidores, no puedo ver los proyectos ni el project explorer ni en el package explorer. ¿Hay alguna forma de solucionarlo? Gracias

Comment: Has importado los proyectos en el IDE? La pestaña *Project Explorer* aparece vacía

Comment: Lo acabo de hacer. Y efectivamente, ese era el problema. Gracias. Saludos